# Will pointer aliase work inside free() function in C

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory

I have below code set and I can't free the memory before I exit the function for some reasons. So I define an aliase for the allocated memory and used it in the free() function as in the below code ,will it work properly?

```
char *gList = NULL;
void fun(void)
{
    u8 count = GetCount();
    if (gList != NULL)
     {
        free(gList);
      }
     char *list =(char *) malloc ( count * sizeof (char *);
     gList = list; //aliase
      //some statements
} //End of fun
```

Comment: You don't create an alias, you (re)assign `gList` - it is now pointing to valid memory, so you can call `free` on it

Comment: `malloc( foo ;` is a syntax error.

Comment: `(char *) malloc ( count * sizeof (char *))` is a type error. You're allocating `count` pointers to `char`, which should logically result in a `char **` (i.e. a dynamic array of pointers to char).

Comment: You would need to call free, from out of your function. E.g. in main before it returns.

Comment: `malloc ( count * sizeof (char *);` is a syntax error. Also, why is `fun` allocating memory, getting a pointer to that memory, and never returning it? That would be better than setting it to a static or global variable.

Comment: `if (gList != NULL)` is not needed. `free(NULL)` is no-op.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually not an "alias"; you just assign the value of one variable (of type `char*`) to another variable (of type `char*`). And `free` will work on the memory address/the content of the pointer variable, not on the "variable name". So in general this will work;

Note, however, that you might still have some errors in your program.

Statement `char *list =(char *) malloc ( count * sizeof (char *);` looks suspicious, as you allocate `count` entries of type `char*`, yet the result type is not `char**` (as it should be in that case). Further, if your list represents a "string", don't forget to allocate space for a string termination character;

Probably you meant:

```
char *list = malloc ( (count+1) * sizeof (char) );
```

Or, since `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition:

```
char *list = malloc ( count + 1 );
```

Comment: If `sizeof (char)` were not 1, `count * sizeof (char) + 1` would be wrong. It'd have to be `(count + 1) * sizeof (char)`.

Comment: The line `char *list =(char *) malloc ( count * sizeof (char *);` is not so much suspicious as a syntax error — there's a missing `)` before the `;`!